# Почемув картинке высота не сжата?

Tags: html, css, img, responsive

В мобильной версии [сайта](http://kaptn.ru/metal) хотела, чтобы картинка полностью вместилась и была видна, применила стили:

`max-width:100%;
height: auto;`

Но это не помогло, высота остаётся изначальной высотой картинки (687px), из-за этого картинка сужается. В чём проблема? [Исходный код](http://github.com/vikapitoshka/metal)

Comment: Покажите код, возможно внешний блок шире или же стили перебиваются

Comment: @МузыкаСергей [вот](http://github.com/vikapitoshka/metal)

Comment: 1) .mast-nav - position-relative
2) ..carousel-item-next, .carousel-item-prev, .carousel-item.active -display:block

3) .item1, .item2, .item3, .item4 убрать height: 100vh

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: @МузыкаСергей спасибо огромное!

Comment: @МузыкаСергей тут есть кнопка Отправить ответ, комментарии предназначены для других целей.

Comment: @vika код должен быть в теле вопроса, а не на стороннем сайте.

Answer (score 1):

```
.mast-nav {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev,
.carousel-item.active {
  display: block;
}
```

И убрать:

```
.item1, .item2, .item3, .item4 {
  height: 100vh;
}
```